# Testing headless firefox using selenium but it is throwing an error

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, django-testing, headless-browser

I am trying to test headless firefox using Selenium and the below code is giving correct result.

```
From a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install I did the following

sudo apt-get install python-pip firefox xvfb
pip install selenium pyvirtualdisplay
useradd testuser
And then in a python shell:

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://askubuntu.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

But if the implement the same functionality using a `class` in `Django test.py` it is not working and throwing an error.

```
class FirefoxHeadlessTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # start display
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
        self.display.start()
        # start browser
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        # stop browser
        self.driver.quit()
        super(FirefoxHeadlessTestCase, self).tearDown()

        # stop display
        self.display.stop()

    # check if this test should be skipped

    def test_example(self):
        # run tests
        print self.driver.get("http://askubuntu.com").page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

> Error: `print
>   self.driver.get("http://askubuntu.com").page_source.encode('utf-8')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'`

Anyone has an idea where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your chaining. Notice that your django code is slightly different

```
 print self.driver.get("http://askubuntu.com").page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

from your other python code

```
driver.get("http://askubuntu.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
```

Unfortunately the driver [get](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) method does not return anything so it cannot be changed as done in your django code. You will need to lines as in your other python code.

Comment: if `driver.get("http://askubuntu.com")` is returning all the html  content why the same code inside Django is not returning anything? I don't think the problem is chaining since the I have already tried the method you suggested me.

Comment: According to the documentation the firefox driver .get does not return anything. None is what you get and self.driver.get("http://askubuntu.com").page_source.encode('utf-8') is equal to None.page_source.encode('utf-8')